Is there any yaml templating library for include?
I have two yaml files
File1.yaml
vars:
  val1: 'ram'
  val2: 'cricket'
Details: 
  Name : {{vars.val1}}
  Sport: {{vars.val2}}

File2.yaml
include:
  File1
vars:
 val2: 'football'


Now I want to load file2
The results should have the contents of file1 with overriding details from file2

Details : {

Name : Ram, 

Sport: Football

}



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
